# Javascript import set images dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, ecmascript-6

I am using react and trying to import images and then dynamically display them.

```
import DE from 'assets/flags/flag_DE.png';
import US from 'assets/flags/flag_US.png';
import GB from 'assets/flags/flag_GB.png';


const countries = [
  {
    code: DE
  },
  {
    code: GB
  },
  {
    code: US
  }
];
```

Then in my render method I loop over the countries and want to display the flag based on the country code.

```
<img src={country.code} />
```

the issue here is that it is setting the src as `'DE'`, `'US'` and `'GB'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the country code to the `src`, not the image path. You should look up the image in `countries`. I whould change the structure of `countries` to object (or map) to easy access images by country name. E.g.:

```
const countries = { DE, GB, US };

<img src={countries[country.code]} />
```